# Bootstrap 3 popover hidden content is still clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Here is my code:

http://codepen.io/murdocgrjey/pen/LFuto

I tried to close the popover when clicking outside of the content and the button but there's an issue with its content. Apparently I can't hide or destroy the content completely.

When I toggle the popover with the 'trigger' link, it works fine. But whenever I close it by clicking outside of the content, I can still hover the link in the content.

Any solution for this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a link to working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zhIsm
I just keep latest trigger and click it, whenever document is clicked.

Comment: There is a bit of problem. After you trigger one, and you hide it, the next time you click anywhere in the document it will re-open the last hidden popover.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mess with the internal mechanism too much.

Here is the working fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/utbin

If the target isn't the trigger, just toggle the existing open popover.

Comment: Thanks mate. It works but can you make it as if one popover is open, when you click on the other 'trigger', it closes the opened popover before displaying the clicked one? At the moment they overlapped each other.

Comment: @greywind then you will need to manually register the 'click' event to check for existing open popover. I believe Yaroslaw answer covered it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way (will work with data-api too) http://jsbin.com/aRiZiki/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did in order to prevent elements within the hidden popover from being clicked

```
$('button.new-history').on('hidden.bs.popover', function () {
    $(this).next().remove();
})
```

The idea being that when the popover is hidden, you should remove it from the DOM.

Hope it helps!